# Static analysis for Python functional programming best practices?

Tags: gratis, python, static-analysis

Is there a free Python cross-platform (Ubuntu Linux, Mac OS X, Windows 10) tool to check if Python production code complies with best practices of Python functional programming specific idioms, etc.? There is e.g. [pure_func](https://github.com/adfinis-sygroup/pure_func) which checks if functions are pure but it is a dynamic analyzer and it doesn't support much checks.

Comment: Hi thinwybk!  Thank you for the edits.  I've removed the hold.  Can you please add if you have any OS requirements, and whether or not you are looking for gratis (freeware) or commercial (paid) solutions?  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I still don't see any operating system or budget. Also, if it must be free for commercial use, be sure to state that too

Comment: @Mawg I don't think a budget makes sense for a free tool. Python tools are usually cross platform and I don't see OS specifics which would prevent from that.

Comment: Lolx! Good points, both. I just get so used to posting that because most new members forget. In your case, you are correct. Please accept my apologies & I hope that you get a good answer :-)  I would like this too

Comment: @Mawg No worries. Thx a lot.